# Change the time forward

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I am getting dates from the database and for each date I want to change the time forward starting from the DateTime that was obtained from the database until I get to a given Fixed Time (Y). However, (Y) might be in the next day.

For example if the date from the database is [7/6/2017 5:00:00 AM] and the given Fixed Time is 10:00 PM then I want to get [7/6/2017 10:00:00 PM].

However if the fixed time is 02:00 AM then I want to get [7/7/2017 02:00:00 AM] (notice that the date has increased by one)

Note: The code is running, but I modified the code to make it shorter and make more sense. Thus, there might be syntax or spelling mistakes.

My first solution was something like this:

```
    private DateTime setTimeForeward(DateTime date) {

        DateTime today = DateTime.ParseExact(FixedTime, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        TimeSpan difference = today.TimeOfDay - date.TimeOfDay;

        return date + difference;

    }
```

That didn't work as expected when the fixed time is 02:00 AM. The difference becomes negative( it doesn't go around the clock) and the date will be [7/6/2017 02:00:00 AM].

I ended up with the following code

```
   private DateTime setTimeForeward(DateTime date) {

        DateTime today = DateTime.ParseExact(FixedTime "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        TimeSpan difference = today.TimeOfDay - date.TimeOfDay;

        if (difference.Hours < 0) {

            difference += new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);

        }

        return date + difference;

    }
```

I am not sure if my function is logically correct and I feel like I am overthinking it. Also,I am not sure if there's a better way or a built in function that does what I want for me. Basically, I am looking for a correct and an elegant solution.

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: I'm sorry but your explanation is not very clear.

Comment: @Sach I would gladly elaborate my explanation if you point out what is exactly not clear. I am not going to lie I hate dates and explaining them is a headache for me!

Comment: Is it, if the Time of retrieved DateTime from the DB is earlier than the Fixed Time, you want the Time changed to the Fixed Time, but if the Time is later than the FixedTime, you want to advance the date by one and still set the time to the Fixed Time?

Comment: The FixedTime is not a date it's just a time like 10:00 PM ..Think about it like a closing time for store. So if my date is 7/6/2017 and the time is 5 PM then I will close at 7/6/2017 10:00PM. However if my close time is 02:00 AM then I will close at 7/7/2017 02:00 AM. hopefully that helps

Comment: And you're using standard US time format of `MM/dd/yyyy` right?

Comment: @Sach Yes I am using DateTime object to cast the database values something like this (DateTime)reader["CREATE_DATE"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is *almost* right but you shouldn't be checking for `difference.Hours` because there might be a difference in minutes (or even seconds if you changed the format later).

I adjusted your function and changed some variable names to make them easier to follow:

```
private DateTime SetTimeForward(DateTime originalDate)
{
    TimeSpan newTime = DateTime.ParseExact(FixedTime, 
                                           "hh:mm tt", 
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
    TimeSpan diff = newTime - originalDate.TimeOfDay;

    if (diff.Ticks < 0)
        diff = diff.Add(new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));

    return originalDate.Add(diff);
}
```

**Some remarks:**

- If your `FixedTime` is *really* fixed, you might want to store it directly as a `TimeSpan` so you don't have to parse it every time.
- If you parse the `FixedTime` because it's changeable, you might pass it as a second argument instead:

  ```
  private DateTime SetTimeForward(DateTime originalDate, string fixedTime)
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  private DateTime SetTimeForward(DateTime originalDate, TimeSpan newTime)
  ```
- The current implementation does ***not*** change the date value if the `newTime` is equal to `originalDate.TimeOfDay`. I.E., If the `originalDate` is `7/6/2017 2:00 AM` and the `FixedTime`/`newTime` is `02:00 AM`, the returned date will be equal to the `originalDate`. If that's not your desired behavior, you might change `diff.Ticks < 0` to `diff.Ticks <= 0`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the ticks part that would have created a serious problem :D.

Answer (score 2):

In this method, I'm using `DateTime fixedTime` to represent a time. I don't really care about it's `Day, Month, and Year` values.

```
static DateTime GetClosingTime(DateTime fixedTime, DateTime dbTime)
{
    var cutoff = new DateTime(dbTime.Year, dbTime.Month, dbTime.Day, fixedTime.Hour, fixedTime.Minute, fixedTime.Second);
    if (dbTime < cutoff)
        return cutoff;
    else
    {
        cutoff = cutoff.AddDays(1);
        return cutoff;
    }
}
```

Here's calling it with your provided example input.

```
var FixedTime10PM = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 22, 0, 0);
var FixedTime02AM = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0);

var dbTime = new DateTime(2018, 6, 20, 5, 0, 0);

var dt1 = GetClosingTime(FixedTime10PM, dbTime);
var dt2 = GetClosingTime(FixedTime02AM, dbTime);

Console.WriteLine(dt1.ToLongDateString() + " " + dt1.ToLongTimeString());
Console.WriteLine(dt2.ToLongDateString() + " " + dt2.ToLongTimeString());
```

And here's my output:

[image]

---

### EDIT:

Simplified method based on suggestions in comments:

```
static DateTime GetClosingTime(DateTime fixedTime, DateTime dbTime)
{
    var cutoff = new DateTime(dbTime.Year, dbTime.Month, dbTime.Day, fixedTime.Hour, fixedTime.Minute, fixedTime.Second);
    return dbTime < cutoff ? cutoff : cutoff.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: This is better than my answer! You could even replace the whole `if.. else` statement with just `return dbTime <= cutoff ? cutoff : cutoff.AddDays(1);`. The OP should decide whether he needs to use `<` or `<=` though.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed thanks! However, isn't `cutoff ? cutoff : cutoff.AddDays(1)` really a disguised `if-else` if you think about it?

Comment: Yes, it gives the same result. It's just a shorter version, that's all :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer sadly I can accept only one so I went with first come first serve :D.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach:

```
private DateTime setTimeForeward(DateTime date)
{
    var targetTimeOfDay = TimeSpan.ParseExact(FixedTime, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    if (targetTimeOfDay < date.TimeOfDay)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }

    return date.Date + targetTimeOfDay;
}
```

I'm getting target time as TimeSpan from the beginning instead of creating DateTime and getting TimeOfDay (which is TimeSpan).
Then I check if the target time of day is lower than time to be modified and if it is I add one day.
I use `date.Date + targetTimeOfDay` as return value as `date.Date` will return date with time set to 00:00 and adding target time to it will already set the target hour without calculating the difference.

Comment: Great thank you for the answer sadly I can't accept one answer.